# Ubuntu One Bookmark sync not working

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, bookmarks

Everything in Ubuntu One sync works great except bookmark sync. I tried the [wiki answer](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/FAQ/WhyArentBookmarksSyncing) that said to run: `killall beam.smp beam`

```
rm ~/.config/desktop-couch/desktop-couchdb.ini
dbus-send --session --dest=org.desktopcouch.CouchDB --print-reply --type=method_call / org.desktopcouch.CouchDB.getPort
```

This is what my terminal came back with:

```
robin@robin-MIDWAY:~$ killall beam.smp beam
beam: no process found
robin@robin-MIDWAY:~$ rm ~/.config/desktop-couch/desktop-couchdb.ini
rm: cannot remove `/home/robin/.config/desktop-couch/desktop-couchdb.ini': No such     file or directory
robin@robin-MIDWAY:~$ dbus-send --session --dest=org.desktopcouch.CouchDB --print-reply --type=method_call / org.desktopcouch.CouchDB.getPort 
Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
robin@robin-MIDWAY:~$
```

I'm a computer "newbie" so it's possible I'm doing something wrong, are there any tutorials out there on how to use the CouchDB? I have Bindwood installed.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Everything works except bookmarks, I have 10.10 installed and updated, I tried the same fix as Rob and got the same error message. However, now my contacts won't sync. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jim if you have a new, different question, consider asking it on the site. You can also "star" this question as a favourite and be notified of any activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it isn't working at all at the moment. You can always check https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Status

Comment: According to the "service status" it's working! I haven't been able to get it to work for about three month's now!The only place they say it's not working is 10.04, I'm using 10.10.

Comment: Apparently it hasn't been working since October of last year!!!

Answer (score 6):

We've got a new version of the Bindwood bookmarks synchronisation extension ready with a rewritten synchronisation engine.  I don't have it packaged in the PPA yet, but you can find an XPI file for the new version here:

http://launchpad.net/bindwood/trunk/1.99.0/+download/bindwood-1.99.0.xpi

I've been testing this on both Ubuntu 10.10 and the 11.04 betas, so should work fine with either Firefox 3.6 or 4.0.  It will probably work with 10.04 too, if you grab the newer couchdb from the backports repository.

If you have any problems with this version, please file bugs at:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/bindwood/+filebug

Or ask another question here.  Make sure to note that you're using the new version.

Comment: The new version of Bindwood is now in the Natty archive (Ubuntu 11.04 beta), so that offers another way to install it.  We'll be working on an easier way to get the update in older releases.

Answer (score 2):

We'll shortly be releasing a new version of Bindwood which will work in 10.10!

Comment: Are you talking about 10.10 or 10.04? I know there is an update coming to make it work in 10.04!

Comment: There's one coming for 10.10 as well :)