# Ubuntu One Bookmark sync not working

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-one, sync, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ubuntu One Bookmark sync not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24508/ubuntu-one-bookmark-sync-not-working)

Has anyone been able to get Ubuntu One bookmark sync to work in 10.10, or should I just give up on it?